# My activity doesnt recognise text equality

Tags: android, database, r.java-file, equals-operator

Can someone help me, I'm killing myself over here. So in my activity I have this code and the application constantly displays that CurrentQ is not equal `(currentQ.getODG() != answer.getText())` to the answer
I can see through LogCat with Log.d that the words are identical. I just can't understand what am I doing wrong.

08-25 05:28:45.125: D/yourans(25316): na život u mraku na život u mraku 
                   this is from log cat

```
RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getODG() + " " + answer.getText());
    if (currentQ.getODG().equals(answer.getText())) {
        answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radiotocan);
        Toast poruka1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Točno!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        View vieew1 = poruka1.getView();
        // vieew.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BD8BDC"));
        vieew1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast1);
        poruka1.setView(vieew1);
        poruka1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 1, 1);
        poruka1.show();

        score1++;
        Log.d("score1", "Your score" + score1);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radiomain);
            }
        }, 300);
    }

    else if (currentQ.getODG() != answer.getText()) {

        answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radionetocan);
        Toast poruka2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Netočno, točan odgovor je:" + currentQ.getODG(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        View vieew2 = poruka2.getView();
        // vieew.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BD8BDC"));
        vieew2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast);
        poruka2.setView(vieew2);
        poruka2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 1, 1);
        poruka2.show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                answer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radiomain);
            }
        }, 300);
    }
```

Comment: One does not simply compare strings in Java with `==` or `!=`. Use `.equals()` instead.

Comment: Or better yet, use `equalsIgnoreCase()`!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if(currentQ.getODG().equalsIgnoreCase(answer.getText()))
```

instead of

```
if(currentQ.getODG()!=answer.getText())
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Java uses the double-equals sign to check to see if the objects the two variables point to are the same object, *not* whether they are equivalent. Since both `String`s are each returned by two separate method calls, they will *never* be the same object.

Instead you'll want to use one of the equality-testing methods from the `String` class:

- `.equals(String b)` Tests to see if the two strings are exactly the same.
- `.equalsIgnoreCase(String b)` Tests to see if the two strings are the same, ignoring whether they're uppercase or lowercase.

There are more options you can find in the [String class](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/lang/String.html)'s documentation, just check the [public methods](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/java/lang/String.html#pubmethods) list.

In your case, change this line:

```
else if (currentQ.getODG() != answer.getText()) {
```

To read like:

```
else if (!currentQ.getODG().equals(answer.getText())) {
```

But for more flexibility in recognizing answers, use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` like this:

```
else if (!currentQ.getODG().equalsIgnoreCase(answer.getText())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

change:

```
currentQ.getODG().equals(answer.getText())
```

to:

```
currentQ.getODG().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(answer.getText().trim())
```

---

change:

```
else if (currentQ.getODG() != answer.getText())
```

to:

```
else
```

I think probably there's blank space in your string, so use `trim()` to cut them out, then compare the strings while ignoring capital letter.

FYI: [Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#trim()).

Comment: who vote down me could you give a explanation for your reason?!

Comment: Probably because you added trim code to it? Idk.. have an upvote to get you back to zero.